# How to display an ActionBarCompat Activity as a dialog setting its theme in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme, illegalstateexception, android-actionbar-compat

The [Android Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) describes how to set a `Dialog` theme for an `Activity`:

> **Tip:** If you want a custom dialog, you can instead display an `Activity` as a dialog instead of using the `Dialog` APIs. Simply create an activity and set its theme to `Theme.Holo.Dialog` in the `<activity>` manifest element:
>
> `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >`
>
> That's it. The activity now displays in a dialog window instead of fullscreen.

I am trying to do this for an application which uses [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat). I have been trying different themes such as ...

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Base.CompactMenu.Dialog"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu.Dialog"
```

However none of them seems to work since I end up with the same error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 8):

Just hit the same problem the other day converting from ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0 (which has a special dialog theme removed in later versions, cause it doesn't have much to do with ActionBar really...).

I inspired from it though and came up with a theme for older APIs:

```
res\values\styles.xml
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_full_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">600dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
</style>
```

while using the real Holo dialog theme for later APIs:

```
res\values-v11\styles.xml
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

Finally I had to use a plain Activity to avoid the exception you got, plus another one where ActionBarView checking it's width / height.

You can read my blog post, with a link to the full source code at the end:
http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2013/12/actionbarcompat-dialog-activity.html

Comment: @drawable/dialog_full_holo_light is not available for SDK minor than 11. Should we add it to the project (where to find it then?) or remove it from the xml?

Comment: @Giorgio, see the resources at the end of my blogpost, it's got a full source project in Google Code as well as links to Android resources - yes, you need to add them to your project, and here is the link - https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res